# PNG images in postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know how can I insert an image "bytea" into a table of my postgresql database, with the condition that the image *must* be a png file.

Here is the table:

```
"id_category" SERIAL,
"category_name" TEXT,
"category_image" bytea,
constraint id_cat_pkey primary key ("id_category"))without oids;
```

How can I ensure that any files inserted into the table must only be PNG files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is to write a check constraint that extracts the first few bytes from the `bytea` and checks for the appropriate [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures):

```
CHECK (substr(image, 1, 8) = BYTEA '\x89504E470D0A1A0A')
```

Of course there is no guarantee that no other file starts with these bytes, but that is the best you can do short of checking the whole file for consistency.

Comment: How would one do this (specifically, extracting the necessary bytes)?

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed!